# Are questions about buying and selling IOTA on topic?

Tags: discussion

Context: [Where can I buy IOTA in USD?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/56/where-can-i-buy-iota-in-usd)

I asked the above question on the main site yesterday. It has a fair number of answers, but has received more down than up votes. Which is fair enough: part of my reason for asking it was to gauge the feeling of the community.

So, to confirm, should we allow such questions?

For reference, the [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), and [Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange communities allow such questions. Not that their acceptance should necessarily set a precedent...

Answer (score 8):

Just to offer the counterpoint so that there can be a proper voting.

### No, they're out of scope

1. It's a Google question. Google even has already an advertisement about that on top of the first result. No Community Wiki will ever beat the speed of Google. The second result is the official step-by-step guide. That leads to the next point.
2. It's not a good Stack Exchange question. Stack Exchange is not there to duplicate good content. There's no real underlying problem since people who consider buying crypto-currencies can surely use a search engine and follow a list of easy steps.
3. Question that are being permitted set a site's tone. While helpful for the people who just read another question on the stack it's not the sort of question that pulls in people that offer expertise to offer non-trivial questions.

Answer (score 1):

Answering peoples questions about where to buy IOTA is useful. But it shouldn't be 100 questions on this topic. 1 question with some good answers should be enough to clarify this issue and the main focus should be on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it is considered on topic, another consideration to keep in mind is that we need to make sure that it is kept contemporary.

Comment: Community wiki, perhaps?